# Does the adoption of a semantic grid force you to use LESS?

Tags: css, grid, less

After much reading on the subject, I have decided to use a grid when creating my websites. I understand previously grids had a problem with bloating the HTML with unsemantic content.

Now this problem can apparently be avoided by using a grid such as "The Semantic Grid System". However, up until this point in my learning I have used pure CSS, and I understand I would need to adopt LESS were I to start using this particular grid system.

Is this the case with all others as well? Are there any that avoid cluttering up the markup, that also do not require LESS?

Should I even be bothered about finding one, or should I just go ahead and use LESS anyway? Obviously I am still learning so if LESS is something I should definitely be getting into then I will happily learn it and implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement any of these grid systems in a compiled form without touching any LESS files.

But LESS will make your life a lot easier anyways - so yes you should take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

in absolute terms, you can't go any more semantic than HTML5 standards. Everything else is relative and depends on you and your use, nobody will give you an award or congrat you because of your subjective approach to semantics. This being said, you can obviously use any grid system with just regular CSS, and you can also use LESS or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) or whatever, I think you're mixing and confusing everything here.

Bottom line is: try to find an adequate way to work, some kind of process or scaffolding with which you're comfortable and that will be it, there's not a real answer to your question

Comment: As I understood it, you can use a grid system with just CSS, but it means polluting the HTML with the following kind of thing

div class="span-24"

The Semantic Grid System prevents this & keeps the markup clean, but requires the use of LESS, E.G:

    `@column-width: 60;
    @gutter-width: 20;
    @columns: 12;

    header { .column(12); }
    article { .column(9); }
    aside { .column(3); }`

Of the 2 I would rather go with the latter, so I will look into LESS.

I was just curious if there was a grid that didn't require you to add divs etc to the HTML, but also allowed you to use basic CSS

Comment: IMHO this is EXACTLY where you're missing the point in semantic code. When I'm coding, I NEED to see if a column spans across 2, 3, 5, whatever columns. Hence, something like col-4 is 10x better than col (and a definition in LESS, CSS or whatever). Even better is the new Bootstrap code where you have definitions like col-md-3 or col-lg-3. This is the non-plus-ultra of semantic code, a code where you know AT FIRST SIGHT what is it intended to do, without doubts. Anyways, as I said, it all depends on your taste and needs. I use LESS myself, but some people likes pure CSS and does magic